# convert string to JSON with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am getting data from the Flickr API with a middle-man file (to avoid crossdomain problems):

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

die(json_encode( file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']) ) );
?>
```

This file is fetched by javascript:

```
//Flickr
var myurl = encodeURIComponent('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=1408bff5f72a4b84b924d13e8562b6a2&photoset_id=77649470@N03&photoset_id=72157629903184261&format=json');
    $.getJSON( "middle.php?url=" + myurl, function(data){
        console.log(typeof data);
    });
```

But the console.log show that the result is an "string" and not an JSON object. Ive tried to convert it to a JSON object with:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data)
```

but the console gave me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token j
```

This is the string:

```
jsonFlickrApi({"photoset":{"id":"72157629903184261", "primary":"7115173307", "owner":"77649470@N03", "ownername":"wedocommunication", "photo":[{"id":"7115173331", "secret":"24900ff306", "server":"5447", "farm":6, "title":"Lounge", "isprimary":"0"}, {"id":"7115173307", "secret":"3435f9a983", "server":"7256", "farm":8, "title":"Hofansicht", "isprimary":"1"}, {"id":"7115173379", "secret":"7747e50597", "server":"7278", "farm":8, "title":"Konfi", "isprimary":"0"}, {"id":"6969093048", "secret":"d4389bc0e4", "server":"7055", "farm":8, "title":"Lounge", "isprimary":"0"}, {"id":"6969093086", "secret":"8e7263005b", "server":"5152", "farm":6, "title":"Eingangsbereich", "isprimary":"0"}], "page":1, "per_page":500, "perpage":500, "pages":1, "total":"5"}, "stat":"ok"})
```

What could I do to convert the string into an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somebody post the answer I was looking for, but for some reason they deleted the post, so I copy it here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=1408bff5f72a4b84b924d13e8562b6a2&photoset_id=77649470@N03&photoset_id=72157629903184261&format=json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonFlickrApi',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This does perfectly the job. Thanks, whoever it was :)

Probably other work too, but this is the one I feel more comfortable. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

Flickr is returning the response as jsonp, that's javascript not json, and you should use jquery jsonp type request for this, see - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

in fact that page gives an example for the flickr api-

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "cat",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: and as @ocanal mentioned in his answer, you don't need the proxy for this

Comment: it works like this - http://pastebin.com/n7WCJrGZ, looking at why urs doenst work

Comment: ah, I see, ok, they're missing the jsoncallback parameter, try this - http://jsfiddle.net/kzETz/

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to use proxy for avoiding crossdomain problems, just do it with [JSONP request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp).

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=1408bff5f72a4b84b924d13e8562b6a2&photoset_id=77649470@N03&photoset_id=72157629903184261&format=json&jsoncallback=?",function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S8MVM/)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON starts with the object curly brace `{` The `jsonFlickrApi(` is not part of the JSON object.
You could string [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) `data` first to remove the `jsonFlickrApi(` part first if you only need the inner, but it seems like Flickr would have a better built-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove that "jsonFlickrApi(" at the begining and ")" at the end, so the 'json string' reads only `{"photoset":{"id":"72157629903184261", "primary":"7115173307", "owner":"77649470@N03", "ownername":"wedocommunication", "photo":[{"id":"7115173331", "secret":"24900ff306", "server":"5447", "farm":6, "title":"Lounge", "isprimary":"0"}, {"id":"7115173307", "secret":"3435f9a983", "server":"7256", "farm":8, "title":"Hofansicht", "isprimary":"1"}, {"id":"7115173379", "secret":"7747e50597", "server":"7278", "farm":8, "title":"Konfi", "isprimary":"0"}, {"id":"6969093048", "secret":"d4389bc0e4", "server":"7055", "farm":8, "title":"Lounge", "isprimary":"0"}, {"id":"6969093086", "secret":"8e7263005b", "server":"5152", "farm":6, "title":"Eingangsbereich", "isprimary":"0"}], "page":1, "per_page":500, "perpage":500, "pages":1, "total":"5"}, "stat":"ok"}`.

This then could be parsed by JS as regular JSON data.

Comment: It's returning that wrapper for a reason, it's a JSONp response.

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned above, Flickr is sending the JSON response wrapped in to the `jsonFlickrApi` callback method.

To return just pure JSON data, you can use the `nojsoncallback=1` request parameter.

E.g. `http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes&api_key=_secret_app_key&photo_id=8321754843&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`